# Create individual schemas for each complex type from large schema file using XSL

Tags: xslt, xsd

Can we create multiple schemas ( One for each complex type) from a large xsd using xsl.

Thanks in advance.

I am able to create only one complextype output schema and I want the file name of the output  to be the name of the complextype only.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="xsd:complexType">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{local-name()}.xsd">
        <test>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../@* | ."/>
        </test>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You might want to consider [adding some information about what you have already tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (results of any research you did prior to asking here) to your question.

Comment: Please include your input XML (or a complete snippet, if it is too large). Good question, though.

Comment: Apparently the input is an XSD. I was able to get a decent solution, but am not allowed to post it until 8 hrs :(. My current solution is working when there are no schema imports in the input schema

Comment: Good! Of course your input is an XSD, but this is XML, too.

Comment: For imports you could use a template matching `xs:import` that does `<xsl:apply-templates select="doc(@schemaLocation)" />`.  If your complexType template creates its result `xs:schema` element by pulling the `targetNamespace` etc. from `/xs:schema` then it should do the right thing as `/` always points to the root of the current tree.

Comment: @IanRoberts I will try that, for now what I have should do. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the use of `local-name()` to generate the name of the file. This will be the local name of the context element, which is in this case always "complexType".

If the input has more than one `complexType` element this will actually cause an error while processing, as it is not allowed to generate more than one output using `xsl:result-document` with the same URI. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#err-XTDE1490):

> [ERR XTDE1490] It is a non-recoverable dynamic error for a transformation to generate two or more final result trees with the same URI.

You probably want to use the `name` attribute of the element instead:

```
<xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{@name}.xsd">
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:result-document>
```

Comment: Thanks Jukka, that was the issue. I already had this solved. Thanks for posting the answer